# ImageMagick 2 pictures on top of 1

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick command-line options to create an animation out of several frames. I got it to work but I need to composite 2 pictures onto a third one. Is this possible? So far I have this code :

```
convert pic1.jpg pic2.jpg -geometry +x +y -composite  result.png
```

This line puts pic2 on top of pic1, is it possible to put 2 pictures on pic1 similar to this:

```
convert pic1.jpg pic2.jpg -geometry +x +y -composite pic3.jpg +x +y -composite result.png
```

Something like this if you get my logic

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how that looks:

```
magick xc:blue[600x400\!]                           \
   xc:red[100x100\!]  -geometry +100+20  -composite \
   xc:lime[200x100\!] -geometry +300+200 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Great man, thanks for the example, that's exactly what I had in mind.